# Laravel - JSON in view / Eloquent error

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to return a specific value in my Laravel view. I define a variable in my controller and pass it on to my view. This is what I get when my blade code looks like this:

```
<h1>{{ $sport }}</h1>
```

[image]

However, since this is returned in my view and I only want to have the "sport" itself I did this:

```
<h1>{{ $sport->sport }}</h1>

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$sport
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you put `$sportvalue = $sport->sport;` in your controller and then `<h1>{{ $sportvalue }}</h1>` in your view ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing an Array Collection not an object itself

Try

```
<h1>{{ $sport->first()->sport }}</h1>
```

Or modify your controller like this

```
// Controller
return View::make('sports', array('user' => $sport->first()));

// View
{{ $sport->sport }}
```

Comment: Bingo. Can see this in the JSON - it starts with a `[` - array - not `{` - object.

Comment: thanks a lot! Modifying the controller worked. I used get() and not first() before.